# Geometry: angle relative to x-axis for a tangent of a circle (see picture)

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Excuse my poor description in the title, I think a picture is needed to explain my question:

[image]

Theta is the angle to the x-axis.

So my question is: given the radius of the circle, theta, and beta, what is theta'?

The problem arises when simulating a car (with heading theta) that is turning. Beta can be assumed to be small.

Where I saw this problem it was stated: theta' = theta+beta % 2*pi. But I want to know why.

Comment: $\theta' = \theta+\beta$ (draw a parallel to $\theta$-tangent going through intersection of $\theta'$-tangent and the circle).

Comment: @dtldarek Thank you! Now I see it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about the rotation of the tangent line and horizontal line by $\beta$.

If you rotate the first tangent line by $\beta$ you get the second tangent line.

Then the first horizontal line is rotated by $\beta$ and still makes the angle $\theta$ with the rotated tangent line.

However the angle between the rotated horizontal line and the new horizontal line is $\beta$ and hence the whole angle is $\theta+\beta$.

Comment: I am sure your answer is correct. The problem is with my internal visualization so I prefer @dtldarek's answer